# Constraining generic function arguments to generic interface type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript I have a generic interface representing a type I want to pass to a function.

```
//foo must be an object {}, not a number or string or boolean or array
interface MyInterface<T extends {[key: string]: any}> {
  foo: T
}
```

So I make my function generic but TS doesn't infer the constraint from my interface

```
const myGenericFn: <T, U extends MyInterface<T>>(bar: U) => void = (bar) => {
  //Why is T not constrained to {[key: string]: any}? 
  //Shouldn't the constraint be inferred from MyInterface<T>?
  // Or be an error since T doesn't extend {[key: string]: any}?


  //bar.foo is T but T does not extend {[key: string]: any}! 
  const baz = bar.foo

}

//No error! Should be constrained to {foo: {[key: string]: any}} but accepts {foo: string}!
myGenericFn({foo: "bar"})
```

The only way I can see to make this work is to repeat the constraint on T like so

```
const myGenericFnNotDRY: <T extends {[key: string]: any}, U extends MyInterface<T>>(bar: U) => void = (bar) => {
  //Not DRY, I have to repeat my generic constraint everywhere I want to use MyInterface within a generic fn!

  //bar.foo now correctly extends {[key: string]: any}
  const baz = bar.foo
}

//Errors as expected, string not assignable to {[key: string]: any}
myGenericFnNotDRY({foo: "bar"})
```

This seems like quite a big hole in TS -- it's silently dropping the type constraint without telling me. That could easily lead to very difficult to track bugs. I'm likely missing some fundamental concept here.

[TS Playground for above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTBmHtwAgWwVwM4BcoCMCmUCGA7K5UArdAYxQG8BfAGih3BSzrhgwCd8Pk2BLHAc05pIAG3S4hWNmywBPALAAoPknRtQWEpgCysgJI5V6zegA8AFSjoAHqpwATBFHIBtANbpZALijc+-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-Krma4r0C+t7SKQSAiGsHYOF25zsr2wb9la0QVsappSOa4CJPyIAAKKkmwThYE4NinmQRy0EGdAMNgCAIDw-A4FgqBiFAR4BgR6pEdyKZptWBTFHWm7ZgmhZSPmpZAA)

Why doesn't TS infer the constraint on T from MyInterface? How do I type my function so that T is properly constrained to the constraint specific on MyInterface?

Comment: Weird. [A simpler case is here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTBmHtwAgWwVwM4BcoCMCmUCGA7K5UArdAYxQG8BfAGih3BSzrhgwCd8Pk2BLHAc05pIAG3S4hWNmywBPALAAoPknRtQWEpgCysgJI5V6zegA8AFSjoAHqpwATBFHJQA2gGt0sgFxRuffgBdX1xZKEoAPmclKCgIcF9zJUolJRJwHGRYWQBxdBw1HhIAMRxfCwiAClQpX10DIw0tCoBKKABeKIA3cB57DqhqqTbO5xTFJRAAOWg1NnA2AEI0KSgeJ3BQKCRZAAcdfUM1JrN-ASiAdwALIqu-K-A4EXscAHIUDGwREXAL9HslDBcvlCiUcJUXPFfAAiGpsaHhNogbJ5Aq8MHbPbocpnfhVOF1Q6NEymXEREbdXoAiaKHb7KAAQQG9SOxmaZKgyJs+zI-ys0gWQA) It infers `MyInterface<string>` with no error, yet doesn't allow that if you do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing one of two things:

```
// Solution 1: use conditional types to make sure you can never pass a "foo"
// that is not a Record<string, unknown>
interface MyInterface1<T> {
  foo: T extends Record<string, unknown> ? T : never;
}

const myGenericFn1: <T>(bar: MyInterface1<T>) => void = (bar) => {
  // ...
}

// Yaaaay! Error! I mean shit
myGenericFn1({ foo: "bar" });

// No error here though, just to check
myGenericFn1({ foo: { something: "somewhere" } });

// Solution 2: Use type parameter constraint using unknown rather than any
// 
// This solution though has the same drawback you didn't like in your original
// post - you need to repeat the constraint in front of your function
interface MyInterface2<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  foo: T;
}

const myGenericFn2: <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(bar: MyInterface2<T>) => void = (bar) => {
  // ...
}

// Yaaaay! Error! I mean shit
myGenericFn2({ foo: "bar" });

// No error here though, just to check
myGenericFn1({ foo: { something: "somewhere" } });
```

The TypeScript playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=51#code/PTAEGUHsBsFcBcCWkB2oCMAuUsDOBTUAY1QBNElUBDaUeATwAd9c7JQBbKga0N1gBOhepFjEqaFPgBu%20AaEZVcrKqABEAM0iQ1AWABQIOgAsq8UIlYpI51QCV8JAaQA8ueAMQoA5gBocKNzWAO4oAHwGXvByGlREhACy9ACSKNECsfHoLgAqYaAA3gagoFqQ2Dmg%20AAe0SikrA5Oru6ePv6wgSHhoAD8oJXYUrICANwGAL4GBiQo7pz0AOL4Up5EAGIoWKC5YQAUAEZUAthJqemZ%20Nl5AJSgALz50pCIpA%20gh8d3j4XFoEYAOiBk2mhjAAE0qFCqPQAISgACiAgEkAE8OSnHwElAuGMFAMHCWKzkiA2Wz2BVK2mwaiOAjUoAmN3G%20gMRgAcuw5Cj5MY5IR4MZRN5jP4AFZ4czwdhEPlEbgEomrUmbdAUqnlQo4yAcfCCrzeGm4HX4YJ8oQMiaM5mgoxQOCUNAAJmwAFUCHQmIRFAIqLr0sRUK0qFEcLgDQEgpBQqBfYK5CZsRJ6GywKmBnjWMaHcg0ILhcZQKZWPGcX7CKRfcEjvLQCIxORSCgAOTmaCIXgWND1%20SoxDeLw0dOMSDzAC0ddEoCk%20De0tj%20GYZhMhFmwdDXlKKLSoEgGknglKnSIjsiaRicUSKXPGUvTtyVVqKwaoCaqJaHgNHS60fC%20SK%20glGUFQslMrL6Gu5iEssypki6OyVDUdQvm%20zhuJ%207SRt0YT7HSpzXhcd67N8TwvG89wfHSJG-IB-xgECAIguBRiQtCcKIsiqLopi2K4vi%20jQcSaybE66rAeodKWjazFgJyVScby-ImAW4qSmwxBygqAlKiSZJqpS4mUsa-p4j4Romma-KWtaoxAA).

Comment: Can you explain why my original version doesn't work? I don't understand why TS allows "T" to be unconstrained on myGenericFn -- it seems to simply ignore the constraint on MyInterface